# Pass a returned value to a function argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get a value from an HTML input in a JavaScript function. I can successfully get the value form the HTML pass that value to other function that is available on that JavaScript.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input value="3232" id="demo">
```

This is my script with the main function, and I can get the value from the HTML:

```
var PageKey = function(){
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  return val;
}
```

This is what I tried. I can just call the PageKey function in fun3 to get the output, but the returned value of PageKey function should input to fun3 argument. Ex: appData argument should be holding the returned value.

```
var fun3 = function(appData){

}
```

Comment: Values for function arguments are given when calling a function, not when defining a function.

Comment: Given the above code, call `fun3(PageKey())`. Inside `fun3`, you can now use `appData` to refer to the returned value.

Comment: Please explain what your actual *goal* is here. What is the code inside `fun3` going to look like? What's the point of putting it in a function? Why do you have an `appData` parameter in the first place if you're never going to use it for anything other than `PageKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
function PageKey() {
   return document.getElementById('demo').value
}

var fun3 = function (appData) {
    ....
}

var func = fun3(PageKey());
```

Comment: Is there a way to do call fun3(PageKey()); inside the fun3 itself or can I do it without calling the function.

Comment: @Ayb You can do it, but it's kind of pointless. No offense, but I don't think you 100% understand what the point of functions is in the first place. If you just want to run code, there's no point wrapping it in a function. *Unless* you want to run that code multiple times, or at a specific point later in time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, provided that you are not calling fun3 from elsewhere (similar to Chris answer):

```
var fun3 = function(){
     var appData= PageKey();
}
//scope should be kept it mind
```